# Can I use the new Samsung Gear VR to develop VR Apps for Android?

Tags: android, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality, samsung-gear

According to [this page](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungdeveloperconnection/developer-resources/gear-vr/apps-and-games/setup-windows-os.html) on Samsung's Developer Site:

> You will need the following hardware to develop for Gear VR in Unity:
>
> Samsung Gear VR Innovator Edition for Note 4 and Samsung GALAXY Note 4
>
> Samsung Gear VR Innovator Edition for S6 and Samsung GALAXY S6 or S6 Edge

Is the Innovator Edition required for development?

Or can I use the new [Samsung Gear VR](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/wearables/gear-vr/) for development of VR apps, games and experiences?

It seems as if this page simply hasn't been updated, because the S6 is mentioned when the s7 is already available, but I want to be sure before getting started.

Comment: I am using Samsung Gear VR which I ordered from Amazon, nothing is mentioned regarding innovation edition.

Comment: @RamIndani are you developing on it?

Comment: Yes I am using Samsung Gear VR with Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes for sure you can all you need to have

Hardware :

- Samsung gear vr
- A compatible Samsung phone (S7 or Note 8 for example)

Software :

- Android studio
- JDK 1.7 or above
- Oculus Mobile SDK
- Google VR SDK
- create an account in https://dashboard.oculus.com/tools/osig-generator/ and follow steps to get signature files

finally follow the steps in getting started (download simple project on modify files like it's mentioned)
 http://www.gearvrf.org/getting_started/

- Run the project

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Samsung Gear VR for such development.

My team has been under development against these platform. Our target device to put into the Samsung Gear VR is S6. Everything works fine so far.

Comment: Can I trust this answer from someone named @autobot_101 who has only 1 reputation?

Answer (score 1):

The S7 works like a charm to with Unity

Answer (score 1):

You can develop for android. However, for Gear VR apps you need Oculus SDK, and you can publish them on Oculus store which works only on Samsung Note (from 4) and Galaxy (from 6) devices.

You don't need the Inovation Edition. I am developing on other two devices, white and black on with controller.

For Android development (Google Cardboard and Daydream) you can use [Google Daydream SDK](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream)